# Create a pseudo random table based on user input

Tags: python, list, encryption, cryptography

I need to 'shuffle' a list from 0-255 but without using a random function, as the list must be shuffled based on a string of length 10. What I'm trying to do currently is as follows:

```
key = "testtest12"
mapping = range(256)
```

I then need to shuffle the `mapping` list without just using `random.shuffle(mapping)` or something similar. My original idea was to add all the ordinance values of the key as such:

```
keytotal = 0
for i in key:
    keytotal += ord(i)

for i, item in enumerate(mapping):
    mapping[i] = (mapping[i] * keytotal) % 255
```

This shuffles the `mapping` list quite well, however it leads to duplicate values, whereas I need all values to be unique from 0-255, just mixed into a different order based on the key. Please write your ideas if you have any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way: proceed through the list and swap the current element with the element having the current index plus the ASCII value of one of the characters from the key. (Wrap around from the end to the beginning of both the list and the string when necessary.)

There is no reason to care or restrict how long either the list or the key is; so the below works with arbitrary lengths.

```
key = "testtest12"
mapping = range(256)

keylen = len(key)
maplen = len(mapping)

for i, v in enumerate(mapping):
    c = ord(key[i % keylen])
    t = (i + c) % maplen
    mapping[i] = mapping[t]
    mapping[t] = v
```

Warning: from a cryptographic standpoint this is probably rubbish.

Comment: It is for use in cryptography, however it does shuffle the list quite well, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I presume this is an assignment to *learn* cryptography, because just shuffling a list in general is not cryptographically secure.

Comment: It is primarily, im planning to use this list to encrypt a file using a substitution cipher, which then passes the newly encrypted list into a permutation cipher for the final encryption. I am aware it wont be the most secure encryption ever, but im hoping it will be sufficient

Comment: @WillGolledge Sufficient for what? Just a single substitution followed by a single permutation won't generate anything near the security provided by, for example AES.

Comment: Just sufficient for a reasonable mark in my assignment, im also planning to do a few rounds, not that it will probably make much difference..

Comment: I dont think I could make something even close to the security of AES haha

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do seems to be to still use `random` which is a **pseudo**-random number generator and **seed** it with the given string:

```
random.shuffle(x, random.seed("testtest12"))
```

where `x` is the list. This will shuffle the list based on the seed "testtest12", i.e. it will always generate the same shuffled list depending on the input.

So this seems to work:

```
import random
from random import shuffle
x = [[i] for i in range(0, 255)]
shuffle(x, random.seed("testtest12"))
print x
```

Note that Python uses the Mersenne twister as default random number generator, and the Mersenne twister is not cryptographically secure. If you want to have a truly cryptographically secure random number generator you need to use one of the DRBG's defined in NIST SP800-90A and a large enough seed.

Comment: Thanks, i'm unsure as to whether I can use the shuffle function with a seed, but if so this looks good thanks.

Comment: Yeah if this is an assignment then you may want to check out other answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that a ten character string does not have enough entropy (=randomness) to properly shuffle a 256 item list.  There are 256! possible shuffle orders of the list, and a ten character string cannot hold that many alternatives.  There are possible shuffles that will never be reached under your system.

Your limited input is restricting the possible outputs of your system.  That may or may not be important, but it is something you need to consider in your design.

Comment: This has given me some good food for thought, thank you for your input.